# Handle multiple request at same time in java mysql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, web-services

I am working on restful web services in java hibenrate , in that when a service is requested by a client , it need updates a row as occupied in MySQL table and provide that record.

My table look like

```
ID   Name   Occupied_Status 
1    Vicky   0
2    Rocky   0
```

I need to update first record is occupied_status as 1.

> update table set occupied_status =1 where id = 1

and

> select * from table where occupied_status =1 limit 1

It works good for single request at a time.But my problem is when multiple request hit the service at the same time its updates same row as occupied and return that same record for all those request.I need to provide individual record for each request which is not occupied before by any request.Please help me out to handle this.

Comment: Are your requests identified with ID or Name?

Comment: For a request it has to provide available record which status = 0 .

Answer (score 0):

For the first, you could use

```
update table set occupied_status =1 where id = 1 and occupied_status =0
```

And test the number of rows modified (0 means it wasn't free)

The following is not guaranteed to return a unique row; multiple requests can always get the same row!

```
select * from table where occupied_status =1 limit 1
```

You'd have to use locking to read-modify-write and get a unique row.

Comment: But it  has to update new record as occupied and return that record.For every request it has to update and return new record

Comment: So you want to `select` and then `update`?  In that case you'd need to lock the table before selecting, and unlock after updating.

Comment: But if i lock that table it will not work for other users right

Comment: Lock, select to get Id, update to reserve, unlock, and then start servicing request.  Other requests will be delayed slightly waiting for the table to be unlocked, which will be right away.

Comment: If you have multiple threads serving requests, you could assign a different ID to each thread, eliminating the need to determine which "row" is free, which eliminates the need for locking the table, since there become a 1-to-1 correspondence between thread and row.